# Find the inverse of all $\{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ modulo $8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the inverse of all $\{1, 3, 5, 7\}$ modulo $8.$ What do you observe? Can you explain this?

I noticed that they are all inverses of themselves. But I do not know why this occur. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? What's got you confused?

Comment: Also make the observation that the polynomial equation $x^2-1=0$ has more solutions than its degree. (modulo $8$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an odd number $x$ of the form $2n+1$. Then,
$$x^2 - 1 = (2n+1)^2 - 1 = 4n^2 + 4n = 4n(n+1)$$
Since $2$ divides $n$ or $n+1$, we have $2 \mid n(n+1)$. As a result, $8 \mid 4n(n+1)$. Therefore, if $x$ is an odd natural number, $x^2 - 1$ is a multiple of $8$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Thanks Bill - I'm sorry I didn't realize this had an answer on the site already. @BillDubuque